# Finding all prime numbers from 1 to N using GCD (An alternate approach to sieve-of-eratosthenes)

Tags: algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

**To find all prime numbers from 1 to N.**

I know we usually approach this problem using Sieve of Eratosthenes, I had an alternate approach in mind using gcd that I wanted your views on.

My approach->

Keep a maintaining a variable if all prime numbers are processed till any iteration. If gcd of this var, number i ==1. That means the nos. are co-prime so i must be prime.

For ex: gcd(210,11) == 1, so 11 is prime.
{210=2*3*5*7}

Pseudocode:

```
Init num_list={contains numbers 2 to N} [since 0 and 1 arent prime nos.]
curr_gcd = 2, gcd_val=1
For i=3;i<=N;i++
    gcd_val=__gcd(curr_gcd,i)
    if gcd_val == 1 //(prime)
          curr_gcd = curr_gcd * i
    else //(composite so remove from list)
         numList.remove(i)
```

Alternatively, we can also have a list and push the prime numbers into that list.
SC = O(N)
TC = O(N log(N)) [TC to calculate gcd using euclid's method => O(log(max(a,b)))]

Does this seem right or I am calculating the TC incorrectly here. Please post your views on this.
TIA!

Comment: I got the feeling that will be much much slower than SoE ... you know big overhead due to recursion, slow operations `*,/` and too complicated iteration when you compare with SoE where there is no recursion, very simple iteration and no expensive operations ...

Comment: The size of that variable will quickly explode.

Comment: The main question about your solution is how computing gcd(i, prod(primes less than i)) compares to computing i%p for all primes less than i. It's going to take around log(i) arithmetic operations, but the first arithmetic operation will involve a _large_ product (that will quickly not fit in a machine-sized int).

Comment: also in case you hold the value instead of prime decomposition then bigintegers will be involved which multiplies your complexity by slowest operation on bigints so mul , div going to be probably much much worse than naive division by all primes before `n`

Comment: The complexity of gcd is not really O(log n), but O(log^2 n). There are O(log n) arithmetic operations, each taking O(log n) time. You can only pretend that each operation takes constant time if your numbers are small (fit into a machine word). But the product of all  primes less than N, which is your curr_gcd variable, is not small. It is exponential in N.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yes but not quite, because after 1 step the variables in the gcd algorithm are both less than or equal to i. So there's only a single bignum operation required to do gcd(i, prod(primes)), and then O(log i) machine-num operations.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I think/guess the complexity is O(i log i) for the gcd operation in this algorithm. That's because a quick google suggests gcd(a, b) can be O(size(a)size(b)) bit ops, and product of primes less than i is less than 4^i.

Comment: Just run it to see how it performs. A proper SoE will be much faster.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid the GCD time complexity would start creating some problems as the value of N increases. Like even for N=11, gcd takes log(210) time. This would sieve would be more optimal. @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. your TC does look accurate. Still this was a good mental exercise just wanted to know where my calculations were off. There was no way I just came up with a equivalent solution centuries after our Greek friend here xD. Thanks for all your views!

Comment: @PaulHankin good point

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the time complexity of my approach is closer to O(log^2(n)) as pointed out by many in the comments.

Also, the curr_gcd var would become quite large as N is increased and would definitely overflow int and long size limits.

Thanks to everyone who responded!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your method is theoretically right,but evidently, it's not excellent.

It's efficiency is worse than SoE, the range of data that it needs is too large. So maybe it seems elegant to look but hard to use.

In my views, "To find all prime numbers from 1 to N" is already a well-known problem and that means it's solution is well considered.

At first, maybe we use **brute-force** to deal with it like this.

```
int primes[N],cnt;//store all prime numbers
bool st[N];//st[i]:whether i is rejected
void get_primes(int n){
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        if(st[i]) continue;
        primes[cnt++]=i;
        for(int j=i+i;j<=n;j+=i){
            st[j]=true;
        }
    }
}
```

it's a **O(n^2)** time algorithm.Too slow to endure.

Go ahead. We have **SoE**, which use **O(n*logn*logn)** time.

But we have a better algorithm called "**liner sieve**", which only use **O(n)** time, just as it's name. I implement it with C language like this.

```
int primes[N],cnt;
bool st[N];
void get_primes(int n){
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        if(!st[i]) primes[cnt++]=i;
        for(int j=0;primes[j]*i<=n;j++){
            st[primes[j]*i]=true;
            if(i%primes[j]==0) break;
        }
    }    
}
```

this O(n) algorithm is used by me to slove this kind of algorithm problems that appear in major IT companies and many kinds of OJ.